# Only one file is extracted from huge tar archive

Tags: linux, tar, archiving, file-corruption

I have a 124GB tar archive. When I run:

```bsh
tar xvf archive.tar
```

I get only a 1.1GB file (which is one of the expected file). What happened to the rest of the files ? Is there a way to recover them?

I have also tried using *cpio* with the following command:

```bsh
cpio -iv -F archive.tar
```

...with the same result.

The tar archive was built on a NFS filesystem and I am extracting the archive on an ext4 filesystem.

The build command:

```bsh
tar cf archive.tar archive/
```

Listing

```bsh
tar tvf archive.tar
```

...only shows the first file.

All of the archive's files are .tif files.

Comment: "The tar archive was built on a NFS filesystem" – How? What was the exact tool and/or the command? A shot in the dark: try GNU `tar` with `--ignore-zeros`. Does it help?

Comment: --ignore-zeros takes longer to process but yields the same result. (See the modified question for the build command)

Comment: Have you tried viewing the contents of the tar: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/list-the-contents-of-a-tar-or-targz-file/ ? Regrettably, AFAIK, there is no table of contents (TOC) in a tar (unlike Zip), so content listing would take considerable time...

Comment: Listing the contents using tar tvf yields only the 1.1 GB file that I managed to extract.